# Translate an image with PIL and keep all the content

Tags: python, image, transform, translation, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I need to translate of 2500px left, 1500px up, I used this code :

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('decoupe_test4.tif')
a = 1
b = 0
c = 2500 # +left/-right 
d = 0
e = 1
f = 1500 # +up/-down 
translate = img.transform(img.size, Image.AFFINE, (a, b, c, d, e, f))
translate.save('translated.tif')
```

The border of the image didn't change but the content did, so I end up with this image, on the right:

[image: result of translation]

Does anyone know how I can get all the image correctly translated and get rid of this black part ?

Thanks !

Here is the entire code, it may be clearer :

```
import subprocess
gm = os.path.join('C:\\','OSGeo4W64','bin','gdal_merge.py')
merge_command = ["python", gm, "-o", "mergedB04.tif", "S2A_tile_20170410_31TFJ_0\B04.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170410_31TGH_0\B04.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170410_31TGJ_0\B04.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170420_31TFH_0\B04.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170420_31TFJ_0\B04.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170420_31TGH_0\B04.jp2"]
merge_command2 = ["python", gm, "-o", "mergedB08.tif", "S2A_tile_20170410_31TFJ_0\B08.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170410_31TGH_0\B08.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170410_31TGJ_0\B08.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170420_31TFH_0\B08.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170420_31TFJ_0\B08.jp2", "S2A_tile_20170420_31TGH_0\B08.jp2"]
subprocess.call(merge_command,shell=True)
subprocess.call(merge_command2,shell=True)
from PIL import Image
import rasterio
from rasterio import Affine
outfile = r'test4.tif'
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 1000000000
im = Image.open('mergedB08.tif')
half_the_width = im.size[0] / 2
half_the_height = im.size[1] / 2
decoupe = im.crop(
    (
        half_the_width - 2500,
        half_the_height - 1500,
        half_the_width + 2500,
        half_the_height + 1500
    )
)

decoupe.save('decoupe_test4.tif')

################### test de translation
img = Image.open('decoupe_test4.tif')
a = 1
b = 0
c = 2500 #left/right (i.e. 5/-5)
d = 0
e = 1
f = 1500 #up/down (i.e. 5/-5)
translate = img.transform(img.size, Image.AFFINE, (a, b, c, d, e, f))
translate.save('translated.tif')

# remise dans le bon scr de l'image
profile = {'driver': 'GTiff',
            'dtype': 'float32',
            'nodata': None,
            'width': decoupe.size[0],
            'height': decoupe.size[1],
            'count': 1,
            'crs': {'init': 'epsg:32631'},
            'transform': Affine(10.0, 0.0, 704880.000,0.0, -10.0, 4795110.000)
            }
profile.update(driver='GTiff')
profile.update(dtype=rasterio.float32)

with rasterio.open('translated.tif') as decoupe_RAS:
    RAS = decoupe_RAS.read().astype(float)
with rasterio.open(outfile, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(RAS.astype(rasterio.float32))
```

Comment: What does the input image look like? What should the output image look like?

Comment: The input image is a cut of bigger image (obtained by merging a few satellite imageries sentinel2), but after the cut, this image wasn't referenced anymore. I managed to give it again a srid, but there is still an offset. The input and the output need to be the same image, just differentiated by a translation

Comment: What we need is an input image, an output image, and an expected output image along with the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to crop the image after moving it:

```
img = Image.open('decoupe_test4.tif')
x_shift = 2500
y_shift = 1500
a = 1
b = 0
c = x_shift #left/right (i.e. 5/-5)
d = 0
e = 1
f = y_shift #up/down (i.e. 5/-5)
translate = img.transform(img.size, Image.AFFINE, (a, b, c, d, e, f))
# Calculate the size after cropping
size = (translate.size[0] - x_shift, translate.size[1] - y_shift)
# Crop to the desired size
translate = translate.transform(size, Image.EXTENT, (0, 0, size[0], size[1]))
translate.save('translated.tif')
```